# Как подсчитать время, прошедшее между выходом из приложения и входом?

Tags: android, android-shared-preferences

В методе onStop перед выходом я сохраняю текущее время в секундах, так же я сохраняю время, прошедшее от запуска до выключения приложения

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mSettings.edit();
    int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);
    int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR);
    int minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    int second = calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);
    int seconds = day * 86400 + hour * 3600  + minute * 60 + second;       
    editor.putInt("lastSeconds", seconds);
    editor.putInt("seconds", seconds);
    editor.putInt("minutes", minutes);
    editor.putInt("hours", hours);
    editor.putInt("days", days);            
    editor.apply();
    super.onStop();
}
```

Когда приложение запускается, в методе onCreate я вычитаю разницу между текущим временем в секундах и временем, сохраненным перед закрытием приложения. Затем, ко времени, которое я провел в приложении я добавляю эту разницу. Но в итоге получается черти что, даже отрицательные значения бывают.

```
    longSeconds = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) * 86400 + calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR) * 3600 + calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE) * 60 + calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);
   
    int difSec = longSeconds - mSettings.getInt("lastSeconds", longSeconds);
   
    days = mSettings.getInt("days", 0) + (int)Math.floor(difSec/86400);       
    difSec -= days*86400;                             
    
    hours = mSettings.getInt("hours", 0) + (int)Math.floor(difSec/3600);
    difSec -= hours*3600;
   
    minutes = mSettings.getInt("minutes", 0) + (int)Math.floor(difSec/60);
    difSec -= minutes*60;
       
    seconds = mSettings.getInt("seconds", 0) + difSec;
```

Подскажите, что мне делать? Как правильно вычитать время между текущим и прошедшим с момента закрытия приложения?

Comment: комментарии в коде очень помогают пониманию кода другими, да и самому себе через пару недель

Comment: Календарь и все эти вычисления собственных отметок времени лишнее, когда есть системные: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock

Answer (score 1):

```
editor.putInt("seconds", seconds); // <- s в конце лишняя
```

нужно

```
editor.putInt("seconds", second);
```

---

Если ключ назвается `lastSeconds`, то логично и переменную для этого ключа назвать `lastSeconds`. Тогда для ключа `seconds` можно использовать `seconds`, а не `second`, чтобы не было путаницы.